# C# Tests with EF InMemory Database System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, xunit

I'm trying to use EF Core InMemory Database and XUnit in my integration tests, but unfortunately, I'm getting this Exception:

System.InvalidOperationException : Relational-specific methods can only be used when the context is using a relational database provider.

This is the Class that uses the WebApplicationFactory:

```
 public class TestFactory<TProgram, TDbContext> : WebApplicationFactory<TProgram>
    where TProgram : class where TDbContext : DbContext
    { 
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
                services.RemoveDbContext<TDbContext>();
                services.AddDbContext<TDbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

This is the base Class used in the Test Classes:

```
 public class TestFactoryBase : IClassFixture<TestFactory<Program, CDbContext>>
    {
        public HttpClient _client;
        public CDbContext _dbContext;

        public TestFactoryBase(TestFactory<Program, CDbContext> factory) {
            _client = factory.CreateClient();
            _dbContext = factory.Services.GetService<CDbContext>();
        }
    }
```

This is the Test Class:

```
public class RolesControllerTest : TestFactoryBase
    {
        private IRoleRepository _rolesRepository;

        public RolesControllerTest(TestFactory<Program, CDbContext> factory) : base(factory)
        {
            _rolesRepository = CreateRoleRepository(_dbContext);
        }

    // Tests Here!
}
```

How can I solve this exception?

Comment: Either rewrite the tested method, so the relational function in question is not used, or use in-memory SQLite, or use test containers.

Comment: I had a working structure of integration tests with Test containers but was asked to use EF Core InMemory database. Does that mean that I can't use the repository ?

Comment: It is not about repository it is about some query used inside it (which you have not showed).

Comment: Tests with actual database, same as you are going to use in production, will provide more confidence and actual feedback.